# Meaning of だかどうだか

Tags: grammar

> 「だから得**だかどうだか**早く水槽を見なさいって言ってるでしょっ。」
>   Therefore *something about profit/advantage* I told you to look in the tank soon, right?

I can't understand 得だかどうだか nor how it attaches to the rest of the sentence.

It looks a bit like the かどうか that means 'whether or not', so may be "whether or not you make profit I told you to go look in the tank", but I thought the pattern was Xかどうか or Xだったかどうか for the past, but definitely not X**だ**かどうか. And then there's the other だ. I'm rambling and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In meaning, one could say:

「得｛とく｝だかどうだか」＝「得なのかどうなのか」＝「得なのかどうか」＝「得かどうか」

= "***(to find out) whether or not it is profitable/beneficial/economical, etc***."

Without more context, there is no way I could translate the 「得」 part.  「得だかどうだか」 functions adverbially and it modifies 「見なさい」.  If it helps any,「得だかどうだか」 literally means "***Is it 得?  How is it?***".

「～～だかどうだか」 just sounds more informal/colloquial than the others I listed.  Not everyone might use it, but absolutely no native speakers will be surprised if anyone said it in informal speech, either.

In fact, you will find a very similar expression in this well-known children's song.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QICdEwD5GE